# iOS - undo push from Master split view

Tags: objective-c, ios, push, master-detail

I have a master-detail view, that when you select some row in the master view, the data from detail changes.

And from the detail view, you can make a push to another view.

The problem is that when you are in this last view, if you select a new row from the master view, nothing happens, because the main detail is not being shown.

I've seen that this code could help me:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But only if it was called from that last view.
I'm trying to undo the push from de master view. How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[detailViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```